# How to create this profile page using lists and ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm creating a profile page. I'm using lists for the sidebar and ajax to display the content on the right side of the sidebar.
I tried the following code but its not working.

```
    <ul id="plist">

                <li><a href="#" onClick="go();return false;">My Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onClick="go();return false;">My Updates</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onClick="go();return false;">My News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onClick="go();return false;">My Ads</a></li> 
</ul>
<div id="pcontent">

    </div>

<script>
        function go(){
            var ajax;
            ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(ajax.readyState==4)
            {   
                document.getElementById("pcontent").innerHTML=ajax.responseText;

            }
            }
            ajax.open("get","fullprofile.php",true);
            ajax.send();
            }
    </script>
```

The fullprofile.php contains some sample text. so if i click on 'My page' the 'pcontent' section should display the sample text in fullprofile.php.

Comment: Why you don't try with jQuery, that gives you cross browser compatiblity?

Comment: Actually i don't know jQuery:)

Comment: Even you don't know javascript, so start learning jQuery which is more popular, easy to learn, cross browser compatible.

Comment: my question was with the above code. what is wrong?

Comment: put your script code before </head> tag instead of you own choise,  check the error in browser console(chrome),

Comment: @jogesh_pi - actually, unless I'm mistaken - the placement of the script in this example is entirely irrelevant - the function is only called in response to a button-click - an event that will (almost certainly) not occur before the page has finished loading. The suggestion to check the error in the console however, is a good one.